# Bitbucket Add POST HOOK using API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I can see that it is possible to add a git hook to Bitbucket in the interface like so:

[image]

Is it possible to add a `POST` hook like this using Bitbucket's API instead of using the web interface? Is it possible to remove an existing hook using the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[services](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/services+Resource#servicesResource-POSTanewservice) resource might help you.

#### Create a POST service example:

```
curl -u tutorials:8798987 -X POST https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/tutorials/testrepo/services/ -d "type=POST&URL=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org/post"
```

This will create a new POST hook with `https://bitbucket.org/post` as URL:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "service": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "URL",
                "value": "https://bitbucket.org/post"
            }
        ],
        "type": "POST"
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AaronBrager Point taken. I missed that in my initial post. I've updated the answer with the example from wiki. Thanks for the heads up!